# Difficulty Trying to Install and Update App

Tags: java, android, mobile

I referenced a question here about how one might approach (outside of Google Play) having an app essentially update itself. For testing, I simply wanted to try to see if I could get it to download and install. Unfortunately, I get a parse error.

I would greatly appreciate any help:

A snippet from the class that calls the AsyncTask class:

```
public class downloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;
    private long localUpdate;
    private long remoteUpdate = 20;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context c, Intent i) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SharedPreferences preferences = c.getSharedPreferences("config", c.MODE_PRIVATE);
                final String store = preferences.getString("store", "");
                final String id = preferences.getString("id", "");

                final long lastUpdated = preferences.getLong("updated", 0);
                // autoUpdate app
                appUpdater updater = new appUpdater(c);

                try {
                    updater.execute(new URL("http://midamcorp.com/myApp.php"));
                } catch (Exception e) {Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), " " + e.getMessage()); }
```

and the appUpdater class:

```
public class appUpdater extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {
   private Context c;
public  appUpdater(Context context) {
    this.c = context;
}

    protected String doInBackground(URL... appUrl) {
        String location = c.getFilesDir() + "/app.apk";
        try {
            URL url = appUrl[0];
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(location);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;

            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        output.close();
        input.close();

        } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        return location;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String saveLocation) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Log.i("Location of app is: ", " " + saveLocation);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(saveLocation)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Please note, the URL is linked to a PHP file that forces a download because the server I have it on has trouble with .apk files.

Comment: why are you implementing your own update mechanism? Google Play store handles that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that the installer does not have access to your portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (`getFilesDir()`). Use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

I also recommend that you call `flush()`, `getFD().sync()`, and `close()` in succession on your `FileOutputStream`, before trying to install the app.